# Statistics on satellite failures

Tags: artificial-satellite

Are there any statistics on satellite failures and their causes? What would be the most frequent causes for satellite to become defunct (either before or after design lifespan): ran out of propellant, valve failure, reaction wheel failure, electric failure, GNC failure, anything else?

Comment: Failures of satellites where? I don't see how any such statistics could be relevant across all the different orbital environments, means of getting there, station-keeping methods, and what tasks they were meant to do. For example, reaction wheels commonly fail (Kepler or Dawn two famous examples out of many), but not all satellites even use them (magnetorquers would be a great deal more reliable, where it makes sense to use them, basically in LEO). At some altitudes, you'd deal with more surface charging and potentially catastrophic discharge events, elsewhere thermal cycling,...

Comment: Or falling over on the floor before integration with the launcher, like [NOAA-19](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOAA-19#/media/File:NOAA-N%27_accident.jpg). There are many "failure modes"!

Comment: NOAA-19 definitely looks like a bummer. I'm however interested in "failure modes" once the satellites are up there. I want to know what is the weakest point usually - electronics messed up by space radiation, mechanical failures like reaction wheels, batteries losing their capacity, or on the other hand, everything still works fine, but the thing just ran out of gas and couldn't maintain the orbit anymore.